# Trying to check a json file for the correct parameters using JsonConvert.DeserisalizeObject<t>

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, try-catch

I'm using the ACE code editor to gather Json and send it to my application.  Once the Json hits the application, I need to make sure there are certain key's inside the json so I am using `JsonConvert.DeserisalizeObject<t>` to do this.  Here's how:

```
    public void SubmitReport(string JsonStringSend)
    {
        try
        {
            ReportItem RptItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportItem>(JsonStringSend);

        }
        catch(err)
        {
            return View(err);
        }

    }
```

and:

```
public class ReportItem
{

    public Guid ReportID;
    public bool RequiresFilter;
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public string ExternalID { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionScript { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionParameter { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionOrderBy { get; set; }
    public List<DynamicFilter> DynamicFilters { get; set; }
    public bool RequiresOrgID { get; set; }
    public QueryFilter ReportFilter { get; set; }
    public QueryRule ReportRules { get; set; }
    public List<QueryColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

But for some reason, it bounces right over the catch even when I make sure some of the key's are incorrect.  Am I not understanding the correct usage `JsonConvert.DeserisalizeObject<t>`?  Or, is there a better way to be doing this check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the deserializer "tries it's best" to deserialize the object. But JSon.NET supports validation, the "straightforward" way is probably JSon Schema: http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema.

Simple case can be handled with JSon.NET directly:

```
public class ReportItem
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public bool RequiresFilter;

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionScript { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionParameter { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionOrderBy { get; set; }
    public bool RequiresOrgID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This just validates the Json, it doesn't validate that certain keys are in the json which is what I need.

Comment: You mean, required fields? It does validate that. Use "required": http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.4.3

Comment: Since I already had a Model built, I didn't want to have to create a schema as well.  Thought I could just use the Model and validate based on it.

Comment: You can use attributes (annotations) for the model, it will build the schema based on that. Just RTFM :)

Comment: Actually I can generate JSON Schemas from .NET types so this might actually work.  I'll give er a try.

Comment: I'll add an example - JSon.NET already includes the simple cases like required. See above.